# How do I get additions to a database made from one JavaFX tab to be reflected in a different JavaFX tab?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, auto-update

I have a simple two tab application build around JavaFXML, scenebuilder and a Derby database. There is a MainController class declared as:

```
package tabpane.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class MainController {
  @FXML public TabPane tabPane;
  @FXML public Tab inputTab;
  @FXML public Tab accountTab;
  @FXML private Button exitBtn;

  @FXML private void handleExitBtn() {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

An InputController class defines the first tab called Input. It marshals some basic data, consisting of a new account name and a checkbox to indicate if the account is active. When the input is collected, it is written to a table in a derby database via a DAO controller class:

```
package tabpane.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import tabpane.db.NdDao;
import tabpane.model.AccountObject;

public class InputController implements Initializable
{
  @FXML private TextField accName;
  @FXML private CheckBox isEnabled;
  @FXML private Button saveBtn;  

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {}

  @FXML private void handleSaveBtn() throws SQLException {
    AccountObject obj = new AccountObject(accName.getText(), isEnabled.isSelected());
    NdDao.connect();
    NdDao.insertAccount(obj);
    NdDao.disconnect();
  }
}
```

This is the code in the DAO controller class:

```
package tabpane.db;

import tabpane.model.AccountObject;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class NdDao 
{  
  private static final String strAccountInsert = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS " +
            "   (ACCNAME, ISENABLED) " + "VALUES (?, ?)";
  private static final String strAccountSelectAll = "SELECT * from ACCOUNTS ORDER BY ACCNAME ASC";

  private static PreparedStatement pstmtAccountInsert;
  private static PreparedStatement pstmtAccountSelectAll;

  private static Connection conn = null;

  public static void connect() throws SQLException {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/" + System.getenv("USERNAME") + "/AppData/Local/TabPaneEx/db" + ";create=true");
    prepareStatements();
  } 

  public static void disconnect() throws SQLException {
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.close();
      conn = null;
    }
  }

  private static void prepareStatements() throws SQLException{
    pstmtAccountInsert  = conn.prepareStatement(strAccountInsert);
    pstmtAccountSelectAll  = conn.prepareStatement(strAccountSelectAll);
  }

  public static void insertAccount(AccountObject obj) throws SQLException
  {  
    pstmtAccountInsert.clearParameters();        
    pstmtAccountInsert.setString(1, obj.getAccName());
    pstmtAccountInsert.setBoolean(2, obj.getIsEnabled());
    pstmtAccountInsert.executeUpdate();         
  }

  public static TreeMap<Integer, AccountObject> selectAccounts() throws SQLException        {
    TreeMap<Integer, AccountObject> map = new TreeMap<>();
    ResultSet results;
    AccountObject obj;
    results = pstmtAccountSelectAll.executeQuery();    
    while(results.next()) {
      obj = new AccountObject(
                results.getString(1),
                results.getBoolean(2)
      );
      map.put( (obj.hashCode() ), obj);       
    } 
    return map;
  }

}
```

A DetailController class defines the second tab. In this class a combobox of account names is initialized from the database via the DAO:

```
package tabpane.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import tabpane.db.NdDao;
import tabpane.model.AccountObject;

public class DetailController implements Initializable
{
  @FXML public ComboBox<String> accNames;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
      getAccCBoxView();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DetailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    accNames.getSelectionModel().select(0);
  }

  public void getAccCBoxView() throws SQLException
  {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    NdDao.connect();//
    TreeMap<Integer, AccountObject> map = NdDao.selectAccounts() ;
    NdDao.disconnect();//
    AccountObject obj ;
    Iterator<AccountObject> li = map.values().iterator();
    while (li.hasNext()){
      obj = li.next();
      list.add(obj.getAccName());
    }
    accNames.setItems(list);
  } 
}
```

To begin with, there is one entry In the databse table “L Enqvist”. In the detail tab combo box, this looks like this:
[![Fig 1][1]][1]

Fig 1.

I then enter a new name via the Input tab and press Save:
[![Fig 2][2]][2]

Fig 2

A dump of the ACCOUNTS table shows that the addition has been successful:

```
ACCNAME ISENABLED
L Enqvist   false
K Berg      false
```

If I then click the Account tab, I would expect to find this in the combo box:
[![Fig 3][3]][3]
Fig 3.

However, the combobox is not updated and all I see is the view in Fig 1. I really don’t have a clue how to proceed and would greatly appreciate some pointers, maybe the code required to get this working as expected or some specific reference information. I have found nothing so far in extensive searches on the internet and wonder if this kind of implementation is in fact possible.

```
In first approach I get the following error dump:

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tabpane.view.MainController.reloadAccounts(MainController.java:31)
    at tabpane.view.MainController.lambda$initialize$0(MainController.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab$1.invalidated(Tab.java:209)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab.setSelected(Tab.java:185)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:722)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:735)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:656)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior.selectTab(TabPaneBehavior.java:122)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1332)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1317)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I experimented with a number of different paths without success:

```
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("./DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("src/view/DetailView.fxml")).getController();
detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/src/view/DetailView.fxml")).getController();
```

My project heirarchy looks like above:
[![Fig 4][4]][4]

EDIT 3 Possible Solution

1. Move the Account combo box from the Detail pane to the MainController.
2. With SceneBuilder move the combo box to coordinates that make it appear it is part of the `detailPane` tab. Also in SB create a reference to `accNames` and a reference to a method to control it, ie, `handleAccNamesCBox()`.
3. Set the combo box to visible when the accountTab is clicked in MainController.

   public class MainController implements Initializable    {
           @FXML public TabPane tabPane;
           @FXML public Tab inputTab;
           @FXML public Tab accountTab;
           @FXML public ComboBox accNames;

   ```
       private static String selectedAccount;

       @Override
       public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) { 
         try {
           accNames.setVisible(false);
           loadAccounts();
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

         accountTab.setOnSelectionChanged(event -> {
           try {
             loadAccounts();
             accNames.setVisible(true);
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
         });

         inputTab.setOnSelectionChanged(event -> { 
           accNames.setVisible(false);         
         });

         accNames.getSelectionModel().select(0);
       }

       @FXML private void handleAccNamesCBox () {
         try {
           selectedAccount = accNames.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
         } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
       }

       public static String setSelectedAccount() {
         return selectedAccount;
       }


       public void loadAccounts() throws SQLException
       {
         ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         NdDao.connect();//
         TreeMap<Integer, AccountObject> map = NdDao.selectAccounts() ;
         NdDao.disconnect();//
         AccountObject obj ;
         Iterator<AccountObject> li = map.values().iterator();
         while (li.hasNext()){
           obj = li.next();
           list.add(obj.getAccName());
         }
         accNames.setItems(list);
       } 

       @FXML private void handleExitBtn() {
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }
   ```

The input controller and inputPane are unchanged and most of the handling logic stripped out of the detailPane:

```
public class DetailController implements Initializable{

  @FXML private AnchorPane detailPane;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {}

}
```

A solution is still required to retrieve the selected value from the MainController and do something with it in the DetailController, but at least the combo box update is now working as expected. I am now convinced after days of wasted effort trying to resolve the persistent nullpointer exception when trying to load the tabs in some way, that there is no other solution and that the autoupdate feature on JavaFX via object properties does not work in the way I had originally hoped for. Its fine when updating objects in the same view but breals down when one tries to update objects from one view like one tab and get the updated result in another view, ie a different tab.

Comment: did you check my answer? Just curious,... If you find helpful/unnecessary/need-to-update/unrelated-answer, please let me know.

Comment: @Shekar With First Approach I do not seem to be able to find the class that 'detailController' needs. Please see the edit details I have attached. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get fcontroller from `detailController = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/tabpane/view/DetailView.fxml")).getController();`

Comment: No I was not successful with that. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Tried to isolate the loader problem with the code shown in my latest edit.

Comment: Ok! I suspect that you need to load controller from one of the `FXMLController`  or Main Javafx class which extends `Application` class - for ex: `MainController` or `InputController` - you're running `NewMain` which is not linked with javafx application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204667/discussion-between-shekhar-rai-and-rusty).

Comment: re chat I'll get back to you as I have to go out for a few hours, also have to be in hospital tomorrow so might be a day or more before resuming the troubleshoot, but very many thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Yeah sure - when you free join the chat :)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204667/discussion-between-shekhar-rai-and-rusty

Comment: _I experimented with a number of different paths_ - specification is nothing to experiment with ;) Instead, read the api doc carefully and follow it. The basic strategy to solve complex problems is to reduce complexity, separate into smaller separate blocks and tackle them one after another ..

Comment: that said: you are on the correct track (reducing complexity in your standalone NewMain), just too much or not enough (depending on perspective :) Not enough: when checking if a resource is findable, a fxml isn't a good example - correct loading has inherent complexity. Too much: accessing the controller loaded by fxml requires to a) actually _load_ it (you don't that's why you see the NPE) _and_ b) loading after the fx toolkit having been initialized (you don't by not extending Application)

Comment: @kleopatra "fxml is not a good example" - but I am trying to load an object defined in an fxml file. I'm confused by your comment. What other than a fxml file should I be attempting to load? You recommend I read the api doc carefully but the only information in there is "public class FXMLLoader - extends Object
 - Loads an object hierarchy from an XML document." I don't find that very informative.

Comment: @Shekar Rai I have posted an edit with a suggested solution.

Comment: @Shekar Rai Can we resume our chat sometime? Thanks

Comment: I reduced the complexity of the main class as previously suggested. @c0der informed me in a different post that I basically did not know about how to refer to the embeddedView’s controller and helped me solve the problem. He  referred me to the article [FXML composition – how to get the controller of an included FXML](http://blog.buildpath.de/fxml-composition-how-to-get-the-controller-of-an-included-fxml-view-nested-controllers/)  which provided me with the tutorial level of information I needed to fill the gap in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be to access the controller view of the relevant tab from the main controller by embedding a reference to the tab’s controller in the main controller and then perform whatever operations you need via the controller on the embedded tab’s GUI. So the main controller now looks like this:

```
package tabpane.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
  @FXML private TabPane tabPane;
  // Inject input tab content.
  @FXML private Tab inputTab;
  // Inject input tab controller
  @FXML private InputController includedInputViewController;
  // Inject account detail tab.
  @FXML private Tab detailTab;
  // Inject account detail tab controller
  @FXML private DetailController includedDetailViewController;
  @FXML private Button exitBtn;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {     
    detailTab.setOnSelectionChanged(event -> {
      reloadAccounts();
    });
  }

  private void reloadAccounts() {
    try {
      includedDetailViewController.getAccCBoxView();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    includedDetailViewController.accNames.getSelectionModel().select(0);
  }

  @FXML private void handleExitBtn() {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

The reference mapping from the main controller to the fxml view can be seen in the `fx:include` statements in the main fxml. Its important to be aware that the embedded view id in the fxml must be appended with `Controller` in the main controller. That is an fxml naming convention for this kind of embedded view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tabpane.view.MainController">
 <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="inputTab" closable="false" text="Input">
            <content> 
               <fx:include fx:id="includedInputView" source="InputView.fxml" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="detailTab" closable="false" text="Detail">
            <content> 
               <fx:include fx:id="includedDetailView" source="DetailView.fxml" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
      <Button fx:id="exitBtn" layoutX="529.0" layoutY="345.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExitBtn" text="Exit" />
   </children>

</AnchorPane>
```

In this application, an updated view of the combo box is always performed when the user clicks the Account tab from the `MainController` view. So if one updates the database via the Input tab and then clicks the Account tab, the updated view of the database is always presented in the Account tab combo box accNames. The Detail controller now looks like this:

```
package tabpane.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import tabpane.db.NdDao;
import tabpane.model.AccountObject;

public class DetailController implements Initializable 
{
  @FXML protected ComboBox<String> accNames;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
      getAccCBoxView();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {}
    accNames.getSelectionModel().select(0);
  }

  public void getAccCBoxView() throws SQLException
  {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    NdDao.connect();//
    TreeMap<Integer, AccountObject> map = NdDao.selectAccounts() ;
    NdDao.disconnect();//
    AccountObject obj ;
    Iterator<AccountObject> li = map.values().iterator();
    while (li.hasNext()){
      obj = li.next();
      list.add(obj.getAccName());
    }
    accNames.setItems(list);
  } 
}
```

For the record the input view and controller look much the same as before:

```
package tabpane.view;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import tabpane.db.NdDao;
import tabpane.model.AccountObject;

public class InputController implements Initializable   {
  @FXML private TextField accName;
  @FXML private CheckBox isEnabled; 

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {}

  @FXML private void handleSaveBtn() throws SQLException {
    AccountObject obj = new AccountObject(accName.getText(), isEnabled.isSelected());
    NdDao.connect();
    NdDao.insertAccount(obj);
    NdDao.disconnect(); 
  }
}
```

Input View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tabpane.view.InputController">
   <children>
      <Label ellipsisString="" graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="92.0" text="Account holder:" textFill="MAGENTA" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="isEnabled" ellipsisString="" graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="137.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="132.0" text="Enable" textFill="MAGENTA" />
      <TextField fx:id="accName" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="245.0" />
      <Button fx:id="saveBtn" layoutX="239.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSaveBtn" style="-fx-background-color: green;" text="Save" textFill="#eeecec" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The reference in one of my comments above to the FXML composition document is especially useful if one finds this a bit confusing to start with.